# when expire date entered, automatic slash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native, validation

There is a credit card component. It asks the user to enter credit card information. However, I want to automatically put a slash between the day and month when the user enters the credit card expiration date. I searched the expiration date entry as "auto slash when 2 digits are entered" but I haven't been successful yet.

i can write; 0614

The format i want; 06/14

How can I solve it?

**js**

```
const [expDateValidationState, setExpDateValidationState] = useState({
  error: false,
  helperText: '',
});

const expDateOnChange = (event) => {
  if (expDateValidator(event.target.value)) {
    setExpDateValidationState({ error: false, helperText: '' });
    setPaymentInfo({
      ...paymentInfo,
      expDate: event.target.value === '' ? null : event.target.value,
    });
  } else {
    setExpDateValidationState({
      error: true,
      helperText: 'Please enter your expire date.',
    });
    setPaymentInfo({
      ...paymentInfo,
      expDate: null,
    });
  }

const handleExpDateChange = (event) => {
  expDateOnChange(event);
  handleInputChange(event);
};
```

**validator**

```
export const expDateValidator = (expDate) => {
  const expDateRegex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$/;

  return expDateRegex.test(expDate);
};
```

**html**

```
<AS.TextField
  placeholder="aa/YY"
  inputProps={{ maxLength: 5 }}
  onChange={handleExpDateChange}
  error={expDateValidationState.error}
  helperText={expDateValidationState.helperText}
  name="expDate"
  value={paymentInfo.expDate}
/>
```

Comment: this is a fairly tricky problem, and a library was written to address it: look for react-native-masked-text-input

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
const expDateOnChange = (event) => {
  if (expDateValidator(event.target.value)) {
    setExpDateValidationState({ error: false, helperText: '' });
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (value.length===2) value += "/"
    setPaymentInfo({
      ...paymentInfo,
      expDate: event.target.value === '' ? null : value,
    });
  } else {
    setExpDateValidationState({
      error: true,
      helperText: 'Please enter your expire date.',
    });
    setPaymentInfo({
      ...paymentInfo,
      expDate: null,
    });
}
```

Comment: this will not work well when the user needs to backspace, how would they delete the `/`?

Answer (score 0):

When I change some data I usually put it in the state. If you also keep your data in the state, you can modify your `handleExpDateChange` to something like this:

```
const [expirationDate, setExpirationDate] = useState();
const handleExpDateChange = (event) => {
  if (event.target?.value?.length === 2 && expirationDate.length < 3) {
    setExpirationDate(event.target.value + '/')
  } else {
    setExpirationDate(event.target.value)
  }
}
```

This can be simplified if you use ternary expression or in any other way but this is just very simple and the first thing that came to my mind.
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: this will not work well when the user needs to backspace, how would they delete the `/`?

Comment: @Abe you can always compare current value from state vs updated value

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion, would be good to update your example!

Comment: @Abe, I updated example. This is a raw solution it can be improved in the real code.